# hapi route joi validation of password confirmation

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

How do I check that password and password_confirmation are the same ?

```
var Joi = require('joi'),
S = Joi.string().required().min(3).max(15);
exports.create = {
   payload: {
            username: S,
            email: Joi.string().email(),
            password: S,
            password_confirmation:  S
   }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`Joi.any().valid()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#anyvalidvalue---aliases-only-equal) with [`Joi.ref()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#refkey-options):

```
password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required(),
password_confirmation: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().options({ language: { any: { allowOnly: 'must match password' } } })
```

Comment: onSubmit it is working fine but on `onChange` error is coming even both fields are same :(

Comment: @FaisalJanjua I'm encountering the same issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: @Amr I was using Joi and had experience of more than 1 year, and I really disappointed due to many basic issues in this library.

Comment: I started using `Yup` and my life became easier... more than you are thinking... I have created very dynamic form with very strange functionality but never encountered any limitation from this library, moreover it is same like Joi, so If you have background using `Joi` you can easily switch into `Yup`

Comment: https://codechips.me/svelte-form-validation-with-yup/
this is brief example how to get started :)

Answer (score 33):

If you got `"language" is not allowed` error message. Oh, you've come to the right place.

Now, 2020 and with Joi v17.2.1 we can use `Joi.any().equal()` or `Joi.any().valid()` with `Joi.ref()` and custom message with `messages()`:

```
password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required().label('Password'),
password_confirmation: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref('password'))
    .required()
    .label('Confirm password')
    .messages({ 'any.only': '{{#label}} does not match' })
```

Or use `options()`

```
password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required().label('Password'),
password_confirmation: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref('password'))
    .required()
    .label('Confirm password')
    .options({ messages: { 'any.only': '{{#label}} does not match'} })
```

Validate error will show `ValidationError: "Confirm password" does not match` if not match.
And show `ValidationError: "Confirm password" is required` if you have not pass `password_confirmation`.

Hope useful to someguys.