# Confirm password cannot be set as required with JOI

Tags: node.js, joi

In my Node application I use @hapi.Joi package for validations. I have the following code.

```
export function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    firstName: Joi.string().min(1).max(20).required(),
    lastName: Joi.string().min(1).max(20).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().max(50).required(),
    mobile: Joi.string().min(8).max(12).required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(8).max(16).required(),
    confirmPassword: Joi.ref('password'),
  });

  return schema.validate(user);
}
```

But this doesn't check if the confirmPassword is required. I tried Joi.ref('password').required(). But it gives me an error. How can I solve this??

Comment: `gives me an error` what error you are getting?

Comment: You should check if password and confirm password are same or not. So if confirm password is not entered that means it's not same as password.

Comment: Please check this reference [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829152/9116995)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate two properties are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708043/validate-two-properties-are-equal)

Answer (score 8):

For future reference

```
password: Joi.string().required(),    
confirmPassword:Joi.string().required().valid(Joi.ref('password')),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joi.any().valid() with Joi.ref():

```
confirmPassword: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().options({ language: { any: { allowOnly: 'must match password' } } })
```