# Password and Confirm Password validation on input with Joi

Tags: reactjs, validation, joi

I'm using `joi-browser` for form validation in *React*. Problem which I'm facing is to validate `password` and `confirmPassword` on input.

The schema I'm using is same which is provided in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827082/hapi-route-joi-validation-of-password-confirmation).

```
password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required(),
confirmPassword: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().options({ language: { any: { allowOnly: 'must match password' } } })
```

Once I start typing in `confirmPassword`, my error comes even it is same as `password` and on submit it disappear and submit form. but if `confirmPassword` is not same it fails to submit that is ok.

What I want is, it should validate on `onChange` event, and if `confirmPassword` field matches `password` field the error must be removed.

Code logic is, all fields are defined in `formData` in the state, and all errors will be stored in `errors` object with same name in the `state.errors`. If error comes, it create entry in errors object else remove it from errors object.

My form state is:

```
state = {
    formData: {
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    },
    errors: {}
}
```

onChange method is:

```
onChangeField = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMsg = this.validateField(input);
    if (errorMsg) errors[input.name] = errorMsg;
    else delete errors[input.name];

    const formData = { ...this.state.formData };
    formData[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({ formData, errors });
}
validateField = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It is all because of the async and await mode. If you would have added logging to the case, you would see that it is not setting the state onChangeField. E.g. it is doing this async. I haven't figure it out the best case, but if you add a full validation and wait for the state to be set, it works.

E.g. I added something like:

```
onChangeField = async ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
const errorMsg = this.validateField(input);
if (errorMsg) errors[input.name] = errorMsg;
else delete errors[input.name];

const formData = { ...this.state.formData };
formData[input.name] = input.value;

await this.setState({ data, errors });


if(!this.validate()){
    console.log(true);
    this.setState({ errors: {} });
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to use async/await as setState has second perimeter which is callback function and which will execute after setting new state. setState({ data, errors } , ()=>{ console.log('State updated', this.state) });

Comment: Yes true, but you still need to add the `if(!this.validate()){
    console.log(true);
    this.setState({ errors: {} });` otherwise it didn't function for me, and for this one a call back function needs to be added as well, so it seems to me easier with async and await. Unless you have it done differently, if so, would you mind sharing?

Comment: I found many limitations in `Joi` also few custom requirements in my forms, like if Field A is checked make Field B optional/required etc. and In Joi its is really hard to create those kind of strange checks.
I started using another Library `Yup` which has same kind of functionality but with extended features. I never found any bug/limitation from this library. it has same pattern as Joi have but it has huge documentation.
Here you can get started https://codechips.me/svelte-form-validation-with-yup/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `validateField` method specifically in Joi schema used when validating the field `confirmPassword`. In this schema, it is necessary to add a validation rule for `password` field, too. So u need to change `validateField` method to something like this:

```
validateField = ({ name, value }) => {
 if (name === "confirmPassword") {
      const { formData} = this.state;
      const obj = { password: formData.password, [name]: value };
      const schema = {
        [name]: this.schema[name],
        password: this.schema["newPassword"],
      };
      const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
      return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
    }else{
     const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
}
};
```